# When is the intersection of a family of CS-modules is again CS?

Tags: modules

Recall that a right module $M$ over a ring $R$ (with unity) is called **CS** if every submodule of $M$ is essential in a summand of $M$.
Let $\lbrace M_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ be a family of right CS-modules over a ring $R$. I ask when the intersection of a family of CS modules is again CS, or what kinds of rings that guarantees this ?!.

Thanks in advance.